# How to create a button in React that changes text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a newbie and I am trying to use React to create a page with a button, that when clicked, changes the phrase that is being displayed but this is not rendering anything... and I have no clue what could be wrong, maybe everything is wrong.
Here is my code.

```
  <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">   
};
class MagicEightBall extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      randomIndex: ''
    };   
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
   randomIndex : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    });
  }
  render() {
    const possibleAnswers = [
      'It is certain',
      'It is decidedly so',
      'Without a doubt',
      'Yes, definitely',
      'You may rely on it',
      'As I see it, yes',
      'Outlook good',
      'Yes',
      'Signs point to yes',
      'Reply hazy try again',
      'Ask again later',
      'Better not tell you now',
      'Cannot predict now',
      'Concentrate and ask again',
      "Don't count on it",
      'My reply is no',
      'My sources say no',
      'Most likely',
      'Outlook not so good',
      'Very doubtful'
    ];
    const answer = possibleAnswers[this.state.randomIndex];
    return (
      <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
      <div id="quote-box">     
        <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
  <h2 id="text">{answer}</h2>
        </blockquote> 
        <div id="buttons" class="row  justify-content-center btn-toolbar  ">
          <a role="button" id="tweet-quote" href="twitter.com/intent/tweet" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary col-2 mr-2"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>      
        <button onClick={this.handleChange} id="new-quote" class="btn btn-primary col-7 ml-2">New quote</button>     
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
}
    ReactDOM.render(<MagicEightBall/>, document.getElementById('root'))
    </script>
```

Comment: You should use "className" instead of "class" on your HTML Elements.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added correct scripts. The most likely issue with your code is with the scripts because I just copied your code and it is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<body>
  
<div id="root"></div>
};
<script type="text/babel">
class MagicEightBall extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      randomIndex: ''
    };   
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
   randomIndex : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    });
  }
  render() {
    const possibleAnswers = [
      'It is certain',
      'It is decidedly so',
      'Without a doubt',
      'Yes, definitely',
      'You may rely on it',
      'As I see it, yes',
      'Outlook good',
      'Yes',
      'Signs point to yes',
      'Reply hazy try again',
      'Ask again later',
      'Better not tell you now',
      'Cannot predict now',
      'Concentrate and ask again',
      "Don't count on it",
      'My reply is no',
      'My sources say no',
      'Most likely',
      'Outlook not so good',
      'Very doubtful'
    ];
    const answer = possibleAnswers[this.state.randomIndex];
    return (
      <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
      <div id="quote-box">     
        <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
  <h2 id="text">{answer}</h2>
        </blockquote> 
        <div id="buttons" class="row  justify-content-center btn-toolbar  ">
          <a role="button" id="tweet-quote" href="twitter.com/intent/tweet" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary col-2 mr-2"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>      
        <button onClick={this.handleChange} id="new-quote" class="btn btn-primary col-7 ml-2">New quote</button>     
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<MagicEightBall/>, document.getElementById('root'))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a number in the initial state, you gave an empty string and expecting the answer to load when the page loads.

You can give a random number between 0-the length of your array - 1 in the constructor.

Change the constructor to:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      randomIndex: 1
    };   
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
```

And since the quotes array is a static variable, you can move out from the component.

Test here:

https://codepen.io/Canser/pen/eYWjEwz